# Log4J / LogBack

Tags: java, interface, log4j

Starting a new project and redefining the logging utilities. With the popularity of Log4J I was hoping to find someone that may have web interface available that would easily plug into struts or tapestery or alike that would allow me to not only configure logging but also view and filter the log files. Can anyone point me in the right direction ? thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be exactly what you are looking for but I use it a lot to review my log files via web interface:

http://www.webmin.com/

I'm guessing you are using linux based system.

Answer (score 0):

[Splunk](http://splunk.com) is great for consolidating, querying, and driving notifications from log files. However for live logging configuration changes it will not help you at all.

Comment: thanks but looking for a built in solution. Hoped I could read the log4j file with a list of all the log files and provide a user interface to the user to allow them to view the file and filter the contents off the file.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Melody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) aggregates ERROR's and WARNING's from log files. It works on individual servers alternatively you can also setup a collection server. In terms of configuring logging, this can be done with an mbean/jmx by tying into Log4J directly. Here's an example article on how to do that [click here](http://springtips.blogspot.com/2007/07/changing-log4j-logging-levels.html).

Comment: thanks but looking for a built in solution. Hoped I could read the log4j file with a list of all the log files and provide a user interface to the user to allow them to view the file and filter the contents off the file. thanks for the information on the beans, maybe its possible to do what I need here..